# Create label in TFS 2017 from Release Definition

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, tfvc

I have a release definition containing the following environments:

1. DEV
2. TEST
3. PRODUCTION

I would like to create a label in TFS Source control whenever a deployment to PRODUCTION is made. Something like "LIVE [Date] - Changeset [n]"

Is this possible?

Comment: Your build can label source. Your release definition tracks what version is deployed to a given environment. What's insufficient about having the source labelled with the build version?

Comment: Hi Daniel, our build is labelling the source on each Gated checkin. Trying to locate a release to production in the version history isn't easy because there's 100s of labels - and I am loath to turn them off. In addition, I would like the label comments to include WHO authorised the release - but one thing at a time. At least being able to organise the labels alphabetically I could find the LIVE easily in amongst the "Gated checkin DD-MM-YYYY".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to accomplish this is to run a command line:

```
tf vc label labelname[@scope] [/owner:ownername] itemspec
        [/version:versionspec] [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)]
        [/child:(replace|merge)] [/recursive] [/login:username,[password]]
        [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
```

The safest way to call tf is by using [vswhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/vswhere) to locate Visual Studio 2017 and then homing in on tf.exe. Or you can call into tf.exe that ships with the agent (officially unsupported).

By using the server side item spec format (`$/project/`) you can apply the label without first mapping a local workspace.

If your Build Defintion was using the Project Ccollection scope, you may have to use the `@scope` option (`"My label@$/Project"`) to make sure the label is created at the right level.

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I will take a look at this. I will mark your answer as the correct one,